# Active directory on MacOS

Tags: active-directory

I am currently using microsoft AD on my windows machine to manage users and groups and access privileges,etc. But now I received a macbook and I wonder how or if there is a way to do AD operations on mac?

I've googled and found that macOS has a Directory Utility, but I opened it and I don't know how to use it or how to connect my domain to it? as when I open users it shows many things related to mac. I wonder how I can access to my domain machines, users, groups, etc.?

[image]

Comment: I've not don'e any of this but you *can* join a Mac to Active Directory, but you might want to look into 3rd-party utility that makes it easier and more useful. A little google-fu should point you in the right direction.

Comment: In order to *manage* AD, your need AD Mgmt. Console.  Since that only exists on Windows machines, you're not going to find it on a Mac.  Use a VM and join that to AD so you can administer AD.

Comment: I just read _"I just received a macbook ... how to connect my domain to it" and just posted my answer on how to bind your MacBook to the AD domain, but now I am very confused. Are you saying you are a directory administrator for an AD domain, and you were issued a Mac for this purpose??? Or do you mean that you were part of the AD domain when you had a PC, and you'd like to access the same resources, authentication services, etc. that you had before?

Comment: @user3052786 yes I'm a directory admin for an AD domain

Comment: @Tak ...unless I'm missing something, someone somewhere had to have had a lapse in judgement or made a mistake. I'm assuming you didn't ask for a Mac? Was it meant to be a pseudo-thin client that uses RDP over a private connection of some kind to remote into an access terminal? You really only want to manage AD with windows server if you want any fine-grain control over it.

Comment: @Tak The answer's that you can't, as others have said, but also that it's easy. Just press ⌘K after opening directory utility to connect to the directory server, and edit whatever you need to (connect using diradmin credentials). The caveat is that it will connect via LDAP, and many (if not most) of what you want to manage will only be available to edit in binary data or other forms that are generally a headache. It will understand LDAP, and the rest (logical structure, etc) is not it's problem. You may be able to make very simple changes though I can't speak to how difficult it would be.

Answer (score 3):

Open **System Preferences → Users & Groups**.
[image]

Click **Login Options**.
[image]

Click the Join button after **Network Account Server**
[image]

Bind your Mac to the directory.
(You may have to click the lock to unlock System Preferences first.
[image]

The AD will then show up in the search paths in directory utility, and be available for selection in nodes.

Comment: but how I can add my active directory to this? is it gonna show up automatically?

Comment: @Tak I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Do you mean you don't know what you should put in for the server field? It would be the AD domain. But you're trying to adding your Mac to the active directory (sort of), not adding the directory to the Mac, I think? They would be two completely different things, and the latter I'm not sure is possible, which leads to more questions I'll post as a comment to your OP.

Comment: I'm trying to add the AD to the mac to be able to control the AD from my mac instead of using VM and windows

Answer (score 1):

Secondarily, if you are intending to switch away from using AD (your OP was not clear on this) you can run Open Directory, which is a direct equivalent in many ways.

In some multi-platform environments, Open Directory is in use *in concert* with Active Directory, where the OD is populated from the AD: I can tell you from previous experience this configuration can work, though it requires you to develop some knowledge and skill with OD as well as your existing AD knowledge.

Here are some article with relevant details which may help:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Open_Directory

http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/setup-open-directory-master-macos-server-5-4-high-sierra-10-13/

https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/25499/macos-high-sierra-10-13-issues-with-ad-and-password-changes

http://krypted.com/mac-os-x-server/manage-users-macos-server-5-4-high-sierra/

hope that helps.