# How can I verify if a group exists in Active Directory on a certain domain

Tags: command-line, windows, active-directory, ldap

In Windows you can use the "net" command to do this quite easily:

```sh
net group /domain groupName
```

Which checks if **groupName** exists in your current domain.

Is there something equivalent in Mac?

Comment: What does "net" do?

Comment: I'd say there isn't one command that neatly maps all the same functions, but there are a variety of commands for managing things on networks. Compiling a list of alternatives to the 20 subcommands would take some time. Is there a particular function or task you're interested in? Or will a "No" do as an answer?

Comment: I'm just looking for verifying if a group exists in Active Directory on a certain domain.

Comment: Then I'd ask the question "How can I verify if a group exists in Active Directory on a certain domain on the command line in MacOS"?

Comment: *nix is a very different thing to Windows.  Each command does one function and the goal is to do it very well.  `net` on the other hand does a whole bunch of different things - so there really isn't a macOS equivalent of it.  However, searching Active Directory can be accomplished with the [Directory Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/319652/119271)

Answer (score 1):

To find a user:

```sh
dscl "/Active Directory/DOMAIN/All Domains" read /Users/user
```

To find a group:

```sh
dscl "/Active Directory/DOMAIN/All Domains" read /Groups/group
```